# Using mod_rewrite to check for existence of a cookie

Tags: mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

I have an *internal* website at my company that I'd like to allow outside access to via a reverse proxy with an Apache Server.

The difficulty here is that I only want particular mobile users accessing this reverse proxy.

I've created a very generic mobile app that will ALWAYS pass a cookie like `MOBILEUSER=TRUE`.

Is it possible to write a mod_rewrite rule to check for the existence of that cookie and ONLY allow requests with that cookie and value through?

Answer (score 3):

You can return a "403 Forbidden" if the cookie is *not* set with something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !\bMOBILEUSER=TRUE\b
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The `!` before the *CondPattern* simply negates the pattern. `\b` is word boundary, so it will only match that exact name/value pair, anywhere in the cookie.

A single `^` (start of string anchor) for the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches *everything*. A single `-` (hyphen) for the *substitution* doesn't do anything, the URL is not rewritten (but the substitution is ignored anyway when using the `F` flag). And the `F` flag results in a 403 being served (this also *implies* an `L` flag - so processing stops).

Obviously, unless you are using SSL then the cookie can be sniffed.